# Why does string::find return size_type and not an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, find

In C++, why does `string::find` return `size_type` and not an `iterator`?

It would make sense because functions like `string::replace` or `string::insert` take iterators as input, so you could `find` some character and immediately pass the returned iterator to `replace`, etc.

Also, `std::find` returns an iterator -- why is `std::string::find` different?

Comment: Mainly historical reasons. Also this bad design got me failed in last tech interview while I was intermixing `iterator` and `size_t`

Answer (score 28):

The design of the standard library's shiny new string class was already done when Stroustrup introduced the standard committee to the STL. The committee liked the STL and started incorporating it into the standard, thereby adapting much of what they had already agreed on (and probably also delaying the standard for another year or two).

Among other changes, iterators were added to the already finished string class as an after-thought. You can see this by looking at the various string members taking/returning a position – it's a wild mix of indexes and iterators.

It's not always easy to guess why some member functions have only indices-taking versions and some have iterator-taking ones, too. In the case of `std::basic_string<>::find()`, however, it seems easy: Since `std::find()` already returns an iterator, `std::basic_string<>::find()` was left as it was.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing. Do you mean, it makes sense to have basic_string<>::find() return size_type because std::find() already returns an iterator and the designers do not want to duplicate this behavior? Wouldn't it make sense to make them similar, improving conformity and ease of use of the library?

Comment: @dehmann basically, if you need iterator use std::find(), if you need index use std::basic_string<>::find()

Comment: @dehmann: Look at it from the historical POV: They added member functions dealing with iterators only where the STL's algorithms wouldn't do. Since `std::find()` works perfectly for strings, there was no need for another find function returning an iterator as a member of the string class. So `std::basic_string<>::find()` was left as it was.

Comment: @sbi Assuming one is searching for a substring rather than a single character, I think `std::search()` rather than `std::find()` would be the way to get an iterator result. But this may not be as efficient as `std::basic_string<>::find()` (depending on the searcher after C++17).

Comment: Help me out here, @Andrew. Why could a function that was designed to search for a sequence of items within another sequence of items be less efficient than a function designed for searching a sequence of characters within another sequence of characters?

Comment: I was referring to the empirical observation that `std::basic_string<>::find()` is apparently O(n*m), whereas with std::search() one could choose a O(n+m) sort of searcher if appropriate.

Comment: @AndrewMoylan: My answer and my comments refer to the design of the string class in the mid-late 90s. Searchers are a thing introduced in C++17.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably more useful to get a number from find because then you can use the `[]` operator or `substr()` to get to the characters you just searched for are.

Also, if you want an iterator, you can always do `begin() + pos`

Comment: So you're saying the bad interface of `string::find` is actually good because it interacts well with the bad interface of `string::substr`? ;)

Comment: I wouldn't want to mess around with iterators when all I want is to get the first two letters of a string

Comment: like it: begin() + pos

Comment: Let's talk about happiness when you are using `string::substr()` and `string::find()` is glad to return `string::npos`.

Answer (score 3):

All the string functions operate on indexes, some functions (like `replace()` and `insert()`) just *additionally* support iterators. So the result of `find()` *can* directly be used in those functions. Since there can't be two `find()` functions that just differ by return type (one returning an iterator, one returning an index) one had to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because in general string members work on indexes rather than iterators and this makes it easy to use the returned value. You can always use `std::find` if you want to get an iterator.

Comment: I just wanted to say that `std::vector` also works inherently on indexes and doesn't return size_type when you search for something -- but then I remembered that vector doesn't have find() at all. Makes you wonder why `string` has it ...

Comment: @dehmann: It has it for historical reasons. `std::string` was first (then `std::basic_string`) and then came the STL with its iterators. When it was decided to incorporate the STL into the standard, it was actually considered close to finalization. (The incorporation of the STL delayed it by about a year.) There actually were already implementations of `std::basic_string` in use. So the changes were kept minimal and mostly only additions.